# Differenze di uso tra "vita mia" e "mia vita", "vita tua" e "tua vita", "vita sua" e "sua vita", ecc

Tags: word-usage, difference, adjectives

Ho visto tutte queste espressioni ("vita mia" e "mia vita", "vita tua" e "tua vita", "vita sua" e "sua vita", ecc.) nei testi che ho letto. Per esempio, questa frase appartiene al libro *Verde acqua* di Marisa Madieri:

> "Di «liscie» ne aveva fatte tante in ***vita sua***."

Quest'altra frase è tratta dal romanzo *Marco Polo* di Maria Bellonci:

> "Dio ha dato la ***sua vita*** per gli uomini e tu distruggi la vita."

Non so quando si debba usare una o l'altra forma. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire questo dubbio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**: nel caso di "in vita" + possessivo si tratta di un'espressione fissa.

> **In vita mia** non ho mai incontrato una persona come te

si direbbe anche normalmente. L'alternativa

> **Nella mia vita** non ho mai incontrato una persona come te

è comunque anch'essa corretta, anche se meno idiomatica.
Negli altri casi il possessivo tende a stare davanti, quindi

> **Ha dato la sua vita** (non: **ha dato la vita sua**, a meno di contesti speciali come poesie o canzoni)

Canzone-esempio dell'eccezione: [**La vita mia**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGSW_gxmkqc) :-)

**Spiegazione più lunga**:

In molti casi è una questione di stile; l'aggettivo anteposto generalmente suona più letterario o poetico, e naturalmente rafforza la qualità descritta dall'aggettivo.

Però ci sono casi in cui il significato cambia; un esempio tipico è l'aggettivo "grande":

> **Un uomo grande**  (un uomo alto e/o corpulento)

Ma:

> **Un grand'uomo**   (una persona di valore, un eroe, etc.)

Però con certe parole non c'è differenza semantica, al di là di quella che potrebbe essere percepita soggettivamente dal ricevente:

> **Una piazza grande** == **una grande piazza**

Un altro caso è l'aggettivo "vecchio":

> **Un amico vecchio** (un amico non più giovane)

vs.

> **Un vecchio amico** (un amico di lunga data, che conosco da molto tempo; può anche essere giovane)

In [questo articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/posizione-dellaggettivo-qualificativo-italian) l'argomento è trattato bene.

Ci sono poi aggettivi che preferibilmente precedono il nome a cui si riferiscono, anche in contesti non letterari: tipicamente, i possessivi ("il mio libro", non "il libro mio") e i numerali ("il quarto concorrente", non "il concorrente quarto"). Qui è la posposizione che dà un effetto speciale, ma si usa poco. Però un esempio è proprio quello da te citato, ossia "in vita sua", che è un'espressione fissa ("in vita" + possessivo):

C'è una regola? Purtroppo no. Al di là del differente "suono" a livello sintattico, i cambiamenti semantici derivanti dal cambio di posizione dell'aggettivo sono in parte legati a espressioni più o meno fisse o modi di dire, in parte al contesto, e in parte alla percezione soggettiva del lettore o ascoltatore.

D'altra parte, è anche vero che se, come studentessa di italiano, sei già arrivata a porti queste questioni, hai già una conoscenza avanzata della lingua :-)